# Load more data - ScrollTop function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to load data on page scroll and for this I am trying to run the following function

```
$(window).scroll(function ()
    {
      if($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height())
      {
        alert("done")
      }
});
```

The problem is, as per my page setting I have done body overflow:hidden and made a container scrollable, the above code is not working in this case, however when I enable the body scroll then its working fine, can anybody please suggest how to handle this?

Here is the [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/n0rramke/1/)

Comment: you may try with `$(".scroller").scroll(function ()` instead of `$(window).scroll(function ()`

Comment: I tried with this already but no luck

Comment: see this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n0rramke/3/

Comment: when I change this, alert not showing

Comment: its working in fiddle. which browser you are trying in?

Comment: in your fiddle, when you just scroll a bit alert is showing, but my requirement is to fire it when page is scrolled to bottom atleast full screen

Comment: @SanjeevK got it. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the element with class `scroller` instead of `window` for scroll position.

```
$('.scroller').scroll(function ()
    {
      if($('.scroller').scrollTop() >= ($('.scroller')[0].scrollHeight - $(window).height()) )
      {
        alert("load more data")
      }
});
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n0rramke/5/

Comment: thanks for the answer but unfortunately not working :(

Comment: @SanjeevK I have updated my answer to match your needs.

Comment: @SanjeevK please help me understand the question better, are you trying to show the alert when the scroller div has been completely scrolled?

Comment: Yes exactly, lets say my screen height is 600 pixel, so I want to load data when I scroll 600 pixel completely

Comment: @SanjeevK the above fiddle does the same. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128254/discussion-between-yug-kapoor-and-sanjeev-k).

Comment: Just tried this code with my original page and its working, thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work (if I correctly understand your question):

```
if ($(".scroller").height() <= $(".scroller").scrollTop()) {
  alert("load more data")
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rhbmxssv/ ...

Comment: thanks for the answer but it doesn't work, what I am trying to do is, let say my screen height is 900 pixel, then alert should fire when I scroll to 900 pixel below.